# Jquery break layout in Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, layout, opera

Why when i add jquery library opera stretch the body to the contents? It adds a white frame

Solved: adding the jquery library in the head of the page, instead of just before the /body closing tag solved the problem

Comment: We need source code to determine the reason. We are unable to predict anything.

Comment: it's because there is no code in your question